# How to force computer not to restart

Tags: scripting, batch-file, installation, restart

I am writing batch script to automate the product testing. After product finished installation, I need to force computer NOT to restart.
Is there any way to do that with batch script?
Thank for reading

Comment: If the restart is because of an installation, then failing to restart will fail to properly install the application.

Comment: This belongs to the install tool and can't be handled by batch!

Answer (score 0):

Try `shutdown -a`. It will abort the shutdown process.